# How to sample time series dataset in minutes

Tags: r, data.table

I have time series sensor data which recorded at the interval of 30 seconds as follows:

Head:

```
   temperature humidity    light voltage time
1:     19.8071 37.61155 137.5400 2.69124    0
2:     19.7336 37.09330  71.7600 2.69964   30
3:     19.6160 37.57370  97.5200 2.69964   30
4:     19.7728 37.16200 143.5200 2.71196   60
5:     20.2040 36.88710  50.6000 2.69964   60
6:     19.0476 40.09450 110.4724 2.80151   90
```

It is a very large dataset with more than 2 billion records. I need to sample the data at 5 minutes interval to reduce the size of the dataset.

Comment: `df[df$time %% 300 == 0, ]`

Comment: select all in the interval 300

Comment: I'd do `DT[seq(min(time), max(time), by=300L), on="time"]` so that it would be clear if any intervals were missing from the data.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `%%`.  As the initial dataset is `data.table`, we can use `data.table` methods for efficiency

```
DT[!time %% 300]
```

Comment: Please do not copy paste answers from comments with minimal changes.

Comment: Perhaps the confusing part is the use of the name `df` for a data.table.